# Swift: How to send cell into correct section in TableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have simple TableView and the only custom cell.
Depending on some Bool, I need to:
1. Show cell in section 0 if bool is true;
2. Show cell in section 1 if bool is false.

Couldn't find the correct way, need help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by implementing the appropriate logic in the table view's data source and calling the appropriate update method on the table view when the boolean changes.

Basic example:

```
var showSomethingInSectionZero = true

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0, showSomethingInSectionZero {
        return 1
    } else if section == 1, !showSomethingInSectionZero {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

And update the boolean and table view:

```
showSomethingInSectionZero = false
tableView.reloadData()
```

Or do it animated:

```
showSomethingInSectionZero = false
tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), 
      to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1))
```

This is the basics of it, if you want a more in-depth answer you should provide som more context and code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, vector is correct, but I still don't have understanding. Firstly, I made numberOfSections and numberOfRows correctly. I'm interesting in func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath).

Comment: I need implementation of cellForRowAt indexPath something like that:
if bool == true {prepare cell for section 0} else {prepare cell for section 1}

Comment: I finally understand the basic concept, thanks one more time

Answer (score 0):

You can focus cellForRow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? customCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.controlShowCell = controlShowCell
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.controlShowCell = !controlShowCell
            return cell
        }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```